# Get WooCommerce product variation attribute terms in admin products general box

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I display the id and sku of **each** variable product in the general tab - of the wp admin product data box with the following code. Any idea how to get the the variable product attribute name too - in this case "test 1" and "test 2"?

**The variations**

[image]

**The general tab**

[image]

**The code**

```
<?php   
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'echo_product_id_sku_general_tab' );
    function echo_product_id_sku_general_tab() {
        
        $children_ids = wc_get_product()->get_children();
        $count        = 0;
        
        // Loop through the variations Ids
        foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ) {

            $count++;
            $pr_id_variable = wc_get_product($child_id)->get_id();
            $pr_sku_variable = wc_get_product($child_id)->get_sku();
            
        ?>

        <p class="form-field">
            <label><?php _e( 'Variation', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <?php echo $count; ?> ID</label>
            <input type="text" value="ID<?php echo $pr_id_variable; ?>"></input>
        </p>            
        
        <p class="form-field">
            <label><?php _e( 'Variation', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <?php echo $count; ?> SKU</label>
            <textarea><?php echo $pr_sku_variable; ?></textarea>
        </p>    
        
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variation attribute names *(variation Id and sku)*, you can use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'echo_product_id_sku_general_tab' );
function echo_product_id_sku_general_tab() {
    global $product_object;

    if( $product_object->is_type('variable') ) {
        $count = 1;

        foreach( $product_object->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            $name      = array();

            foreach( $variation->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $term_slug ) {
                $name[] = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name;
            }

            echo '<p><strong>'. sprintf( __("Variation %s Name: %s", "woocommerce"), $count, '</strong>' . implode(' - ', $name) ) .'</p>

            <p class="form-field">
            <label>' . sprintf( __("Variation %s ID", "woocommerce"), $count) . '</label>
                <input type="text" value="ID' . $variation_id . '"></input>
            </p>

            <p class="form-field">
                <label>' . sprintf( __("Variation %s SKU", "woocommerce"), $count) . '</label>
                <textarea>' . $variation->get_sku() . '</textarea>
            </p>';
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** this works for product attribute taxonomies only (starting with "pa_"), **but not with custom attributes.**

Comment: If the price is empty it does not shows that product. Any solution for that - oterhwise it works fine. THX

Comment: any way to refresh the general tab values as well - after saving / updating some values on the variations tab?

Answer (score 2):

> I display the id and sku of each variable product in the general tab.

In WooCommerce, the general tab is not available (visible) for a variable product, **except** when taxes enabled. Under WooCommerce > Settings > General > Enable taxes.

Because it's used to set parent tax class and tax status so if you don’t have taxes enabled, nothing will show there.

---

To answer your question

Replace this part

```php
// Loop through the variations Ids
foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ) {

    $count++;
    $pr_id_variable = wc_get_product($child_id)->get_id();
    $pr_sku_variable = wc_get_product($child_id)->get_sku();
    
?>

<p class="form-field">
```

With

```php
// Loop through the variations Ids
foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
    $count++;
    
    $child = wc_get_product( $child_id );
        
    $pr_attribute_name = implode( " / ", $child->get_variation_attributes() );          
    $pr_id_variable = $child->get_id();
    $pr_sku_variable = $child->get_sku();
    
?>

<p> <?php echo $pr_attribute_name; ?> </p>
<p class="form-field">
```

Comment: i began with your solution - it works fine. The name gets printed in lowercase despite i wrote the first letter in uppercase - any idea why? thx

Comment: You can use [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) - Make a string's first character uppercase. Replace `echo $pr_attribute_name;` with `echo ucfirst( $pr_attribute_name );`